# Dompdf laravel text overlapping

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, pdf-generation, dompdf

Here is the problem -> [Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq9ui.png)

I'm trying to put that piece of text under the table but it is overlapping on the table.
And i cannot get it to the bottom. I think its because on condition it is making the `<tr>` and because of that the text part gets rendered before the loop has been finished.

And here is my code ->

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Student Records</title>

</head>

<body>


    <style>
        .pdfContainer {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;

        }



        table {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            float: bottom;
            border: none;

        }

        td {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 0.95em;
            color: #252a34;
            font-weight: 500;
            background-color: #fff;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }


        th,
        td {
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #252a34 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
        }

        th {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 0.95em;
            font-weight: 800;
            border: none;
            white-space: nowrap;

        }




        .attdStatusTdpresent {
            color: #18a14f;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 110px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 0.95em;
            font-family: "Merriweather Sans", sans-serif;
        }

        .attdStatusTdabsent {
            color: #b82348;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 110px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-weight: 600;
            font-size: 0.95em;
            font-family: "Merriweather Sans", sans-serif;
        }


        .attdStatusTdlate {
            color: #ff2e63;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 110px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 0.95em;
        }

        .attBehaviourExcellent {
            color: #289672;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 110px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 0.95em;
        }

        .attBehaviourGood {
            color: #00bfa6;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 110px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 0.95em;
        }

        .attBehaviourAverage {
            color: #ffc947;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 110px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 0.95em;
        }

        .attBehaviourBad {
            color: #ff2e63;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 110px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 0.95em;
        }



        .attProgressExcellent {
            color: #289672;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 110px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 0.95em;
        }

        .attProgressGood {
            color: #00bfa6;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 110px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 0.95em;
        }

        .attProgressNeed {
            color: #ffc947;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 140px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 0.95em;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .attProgressprogressive {
            color: #185adb;
            padding: 8px;
            width: 110px;
            border-radius: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            text-transform: capitalize;
            font-size: 0.95em;
        }

        .pdfContainer {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            align-items: flex-start;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .logo>img {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 30px;
        }

        .nameContainer {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }


       
    </style>


    <div class="logo">
        <img src="<?php echo  Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::to('/') . '/' ?>images/l.jpg" alt="">
    </div>




    <div class="nameContainer">

        <h2> {{$studentName}} </h2>

    </div>

    <div class="pdfContainer">



        <table>

            <tr>

                <th> PRÉSENCE </th>
                <th> COMPORTEMENT </th>
                <th> PROGRES </th>
                <th> DATE DE L’ATELIER </th>

            </tr>


            @foreach($records as $record)

            <tr>

                <td>
data

                </td>
                <td>


data


                </td>
                <td>

data


                </td>
                <td>
                    <p> {{$record['customDate']}} </p>
                </td>

            </tr>

            @endforeach

        </table>



    </div>




    <div class="termContainer">
        <strong> Term Report: </strong>
        <p>{{ !empty($termReport->text) ? $termReport->text: '' }} </p>
    </div>

    <div class="footerImage">
        <img src="<?php echo  Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::to('/') . '/' ?>images/fol.jpg" alt="">
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

`style='margin:auto;` Do not use this CSS property. You give the margin size in `px, rem` etc. If you give percentage (%) EX: 50%, 25%, `auto` in **dompdf** it will not be captured

---

dompdf is mostly CSS 2.1 compliant, which means things like flexbox are not supported.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/CSSCompatibility)

Comment: Please consider adding sources to this information for reference

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).